# Winter Bash leaderboard misaligned with long usernames

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

On the SO leaderboard, I see:

[image]

As you can see, due to the long username. The hat number and the hat images are all misaligned.

This is a bug. It doesn't look good. We should cut long usernames and add 3 dots at the end, I think that's the best way to solve it. Or another option is to cut the name into 2 lines.

Comment: This doesn't happen for longer usernames with spaces in - those wrap, see [mine](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/codegolf.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and did a slight layout overhaul to leaderboards for Winter/Summer Bash so it's more responsive. Long names (with or without spaces) should now be truncated, and the layout should look aligned regardless of the content within.

Thanks for reporting! As usual, we appreciate the help!

Comment: Thanks Felippe, much better.